# In constitutional monarchies, what would happen to the line of succession if the heir-apparent is gay?

Tags: civil-rights, constitutional-monarchy

This question is asked in the context of 2021.

I understand that people used to just get married and have kids anyways. But in 2021, it seems backward - even inhumane - for monarchies to cover up homosexualities among its members. If anything, it might even be politically damaging for the institution to do that.

So hypothetically, if the heir-apparent is gay:

- Would he or she still inherit the throne?
- Would they be allowed to get married?
- Would the line of succession simply skip over them as if they never existed?
- Would they still be allowed to perform royal duties?

In short, how would a constitutional monarchy respond to such complication in 2021?

Comment: I don't think that any constitutional monarchy has already an official regulation for that hypothetical. It took the British monarchy until 2013 to even have gender equality in their throne succession law.

Comment: Monarchies have dealt with infertile monarchs for centuries. There's always *at least* one person who thinks they are next in line

Comment: I don't think that can be answered in general - this will differ from country to country due to the different cultural and religious concepts the legitimacy of the monarch builds upon. Even among European monarchies, this will be decided on a case-by-case basis. Outcomes might be different in UK vs. Spain vs. Sweden.

Comment: This is too broad. Constitutional monarchies vary in their minutiae on the line of succession. In the UK one need(ed) to be a Protestant, cannot marry a Roman Catholic etc.

Comment: I don't think there is any explicit prohibition against being gay in any written law (for line of succession) in Western countries, but then what's written may not always be how things work out. Monarchs can be forced/nudged to abdicate (or give up their right to succeed) by various "peer/public pressure" means etc. See Edward VIII (who was not gay). One could imagine that if the official royal marriage was of the same sex, it may cause some political waves. I don't know of an example like that though.

Comment: Although in the UK there was one in the royal family in 2018 https://www.vanityfair.com/style/2018/09/british-royal-family-had-a-same-sex-wedding

Comment: I'm not sure about the close reason given.  If the OP can focus the question by giving a country tag or otherwise then this doesn't seem to require speculation on how an individual would act.  It is quite clear in the UK constitution who the heir is.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the relatively recent history of Belgium.
Slightly different in that the king was married but alike in that the couple did not have children.
The kings brother inherited, as had been worked to for a long time.

Or England, when the king did not want to become a real king, as the country did not accept the woman he wanted to marry.
Short notice decision*, his brother became king.

Most royal families have more than one child in each generation, but exceptions have been around, and the second and further children of the king or queen are also on the list 'in line for the trone' as are their children and further offspring unless a decision is made to exclude them for whatever reason.

I am most familiar with the Dutch royal family, as that is my country. We had the 'only child' Wilhelmina and her 'only child' Juliana. But in the next generation there were 4 children. Beatrix who became queen in turn, and her sisters, one of whom dedicated her life to being 'next in line' or 'spare'. The other two sisters did not apply for permission to marry and that took them off the list for succession, but at that time the next generation had been started.

But that all being said, it is quite likely that in the past there have been kings who did not fall for women but still married and had at least one child. And there is nothing that will stop a future king or queen to life that kind of double life, they would not be the only one in their country.

It is most likely that they are not asked to behave that way but that they either do not feel free to be different (as news papers and such are very harsh) or that they find an other reason not to accept the crown and its responsibilities and being in the cameras all the time, and life a more relaxed life and maybe feel more free in that. (But look at Prince Harry, not happy in England at the moment, due to at least partly newspaper pressure.)

*Short notice compared to the Belgium situation of a later time, not matter of minutes.

Comment: It wasn't a last moment decision with Edward VIII as he did become king and then abdicated.

Comment: @phoog Edited, this better?